# How to avoid branching in C for this operation

Tags: c, performance, optimization

Is there a way to remove the following if-statement to check if the value is below 0?

```
int a = 100;
int b = 200;
int c = a - b;

if (c < 0)
{
    c += 3600;
}
```

The value of `c` should lie between 0 and 3600. Both `a` and `b` are signed. The value of `a` also should lie between 0 and 3600. (yes, it is a counting value in 0.1 degrees). The value gets reset by an interrupt to 3600, but if that interrupt comes too late it underflows, which is not of a problem, but the software should still be able to handle it. Which it does.

We do this `if (c < 0)` check at quite some places where we are calculating positions. (Calculating a new position etc.)

I was used to pythons modulo operator to use the signedness of the divisor where our compiler (C89) is using the dividend signedness.

Is there some way to do this calculation differently?
example results:

```
 a  -  b  = c
100 - 200 = 3500  
200 - 100 = 100
```

Comment: Why are you worried about the branch?  The alternative is something like `((a - b) + 3600) % 3600`.  This assumes `a` and `b` are in the range `0..3600` already; if they're not under control, the more general solution is the one Drew McGowen suggests:  ((a - b) % 3600 + 3600) % 3600`. The branch miss has to be very expensive to make that much calculation worthwhile.

Comment: A trick I used to use would be `((a - b) % 3600 + 3600) % 3600` - though with two modulus operators, you actually might be better off just using the comparison

Comment: @JonathanLeffler we have an old, bad, all but optimized compiler. It is generating bloated branches. I've just checked both your answers, they each produce less assembly instructions and easier code to maintain. If both of you could provide it as an answer I can give you an upvote and accept jonathan's. I've no need for 2 modulus ops. Both value `a` and `b` are under our own control.

Comment: Smells like premature optimization to me. If you have a CPU that supports conditional moves or other alternatives for generating branchless code, and a decently modern compiler that supports that CPU, then it's likely to generate branchless code for you even if you use `if (...) {}`... Also, the mod operator just might be slower than a short branch to code that's likely already in-cache...

Comment: It also generates less cycles.

Comment: @twalberg it is not. Old fujitsu compiler. Even older microprocessor. no conditional moves, no fancy pancy stuff. Except for a hardware divider

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good question! How about this?

```
c += 3600 * (c < 0);
```

This is one way we preserve branch predictor slots.

Comment: @abelenky no, truth values are zero/nonzero, but comparison operators only return zero or one.

Answer (score 7):

What about this (assuming 32-bit ints):

```
c += 3600 & (c >> 31);
```

`c >> 31` sets all bits to the original MSB, which is 1 for negative numbers and and 0 for others in 2-complement.

Negative number shift right is formally implementation-defined according to C standard documents, however it's almost always implemented with MSB copying (common processors can do it in a single instruction).

This will surely result in no branches, unlike `(c < 0)` which might be implemented with branch in some cases.

Comment: Very nice. But you should negate (c>>31) before ANDing it to 3600.

Comment: @SáT No, i want to have full mask if number is negative (MSB is 1). I want zero if number is non-negative.

Comment: Uh, true enough, sorry about it :$.

Comment: For signed integers, it is implementation defined whether you'll get the sign bit replicated.  ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators: ¶5 The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. If `E1` has an unsigned type
or if `E1` has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral
part of the quotient of `E1 / 2**E2` _[exponentiation; can't do superscripts in comments]_. If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the
resulting value is implementation-defined.

Comment: Although a nice solution, this is sadly not allowed according to our MISRA C that we have to comply with. It is possible to make it comply but results in many ugly casts.

Answer (score 5):

Why are you worried about the branch? *[Reason explained in comments to the question.]*

The alternative is something like:

```
((a - b) + 3600) % 3600
```

This assumes `a` and `b` are in the range `0..3600` already; if they're not under control, the more general solution is the one [Drew McGowen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2478565/drew-mcgowen) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748972/branchless-python-like-modulo-operation-in-c#comment25878701_17748972):

```
((a - b) % 3600 + 3600) % 3600
```

The branch miss has to be very expensive to make that much calculation worthwhile.

Answer (score 4):

@skjaidev showed how to do it without branching. Here's how to automatically avoid multiplication as well when `int`s are twos-complement:

```
#if ((3600 & -0) == 0) && ((3600 & -1) == 3600)
c += 3600 & -(c < 0);
#else
c += 3600 * (c < 0);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is modular arithmetic.  Your 2's complement machine already does this with integer math.  So, by mapping your values into 2's complement arithmetic, you can get the modolo operation free.

The trick is represent your angle as a fraction of 360 degrees between 0 and 1-epsilon.  Of course, then your constant angles would have to represented similarly, but that shouldn't be hard; its just a bit of math we can hide in a conversion function (er, macro).

The value in this idea  is that if you add or subtract angles, you'll get a value whose fraction part you want, and whose integer part you want to throw away.  If we represent the fraction as a 32 bit fixed point number with the binary point at 2^32 (e.g., to the left of what is normally considered to be a sign bit), any overflows of the fraction simply fall off the top of the 32 bit value for free.  So, you do all integer math, and "overflow" removal happens for free.

So I'd rewrite your code (preserving the idea of degrees times 10):

```
  typedef unsigned int32 angle; // angle*3600/(2^32) represents degrees
  #define angle_scale_factor 1193046.47111111 // = 2^32/3600
  #define make_angle(degrees)  (unsigned int32)((degrees%3600)*angle_scale_factor ) 
  #define make_degrees(angle) (angle/(angle_scale_factor*10)) // produces float number

  ...

  angle a = make_angle(100);  // compiler presumably does compile-time math to compute 119304647 
  angle b = make_angle(200);  // = 238609294
  angle c = a - b; // compiler should generate integer subtract, which computes 4175662649

  #if 0 // no need for this at all; other solutions execute real code to do something here
  if (c < 0)  // this can't happen
     { c += 3600; } // this is the wrong representation for our variant
  #endif


  // speed doesn't matter here, we're doing output:
  printf("final angle %f4.2 = \n", make_degrees(c)); // should print 350.00
```

I have not compiled and run this code.

Changes to make this degrees times 100 or times 1 are pretty easy; modify the angle_scale_factor. If you have a 16 bit machine, switching to 16 bits is similarly easy; if you have 32 bits, and you still want to only do 16 bit math, you will need to mask the value to be printed to 16 bits.

This solution has one other nice property: you've documented which variables are angles (and have funny representations).  OP's original code just called them ints, but that's not what they represent; a future maintainer will get suprised by the original code, especially if he finds the subtraction isolated from the variables.